# Why and when does yarn decide not to hoist a package in a workspace?

Tags: yarnpkg, workspace, yarn-workspaces

I'm working on a large project using `yarn workspaces`. I know that yarn workspaces essentially does two things

- It automates the symlinking process we had to do manually years ago when we want to share private packages
- It hoists all similar packages at the top in `node_modules` in order to be more efficient.

However, I have noticed that my packages still contain code in their own `node_modules` and I'm not sure why. When I make a sample monorepo app and say I install `lodash` in one, it goes straight to the root `node_modules`.

Why and when does yarn decide to install a package inside a package's `node_modules` ?

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer on yarn's Discords. `yarn` will always hoist unless it would conflict with another version.

Comment: Just wanted to add that sometimes it can "conflict" due to peer-dependencies -- such that there can be copies of the exact same library version at multiple levels. A an example conflict is [described here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/951931842273398784); and the real-world case of it that I had is [here](https://github.com/graphile/graphile-engine/issues/607#issuecomment-976018917).